# gVim as git editor under cygwin

Tags: git, cygwin, gvim

I use msysgit and I'd like to have gvim as my git editor.

I use cygwin bash instead of git bash.

Running

```
$ /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe
```

starts gvim. But if I set this as git editor:

```
$ git config core.editor /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe
```

and run commit I get:

```
/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I then add escaped backslashes where needed:

```
$ git config core.editor /cygdrive/c/Program\\\ Files\\\ \\\(x86\\\)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe
```

This still gives me:

```
/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe: No such file or directory
error: cannot run /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor '/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe'.
```

The thing is, I can copy the string from after "cannot run" and paste it and it runs. I guess it could be caused by either the spaces or the parentheses in Program Files (x86) (what on earth were they thinking?).

Since cygwin seems to handle it ok I figured I could create a symlink in say /usr/local/bin, as it is in my $PATH and set

```
$ git config core.editor /usr/local/bin/gvim
```

I confirm that /usr/local/bin/gvim starts gvim. Still, running a commit gives me:

```
error: cannot spawn /usr/local/bin/gvim.exe: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor '/usr/local/bin/gvim.exe'.
```

Unsetting core.editor and trying

```
$ export GIT_EDITOR=/usr/local/bin/gvim.exe
```

gives me the same error.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows/773973#773973) suggest that I use a script to open the editor.

I remove the soft link gvim.exe from /usr/local/bin and

```
$ cat > gvim
#!/bin/sh
/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe

$ chmod u+x gvim
```

I test run the script, it works, gvim starts.

```
$ gvim
```

Unfortunately when I run commit I get an error

```
$ git commit
error: cannot spawn /usr/local/bin/gvim: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor '/usr/local/bin/gvim'.
```

What can I do to get to use gVim as git editor? Has anybody tried it? Have I made mistakes? I must admit to being a novice when it comes to linux.

Comment: Have you tried using the cygwin vi instead? Have you tried the command `which gvim`?

Comment: which gvim outputs /usr/local/bin/gvim, only when the soft link or the script is there. I should probably state clearer my reason for wanting gVim. I use it daily and have set it up as I want it. If I use any other I will have two editors settings to maintain.

Comment: You may want to consider using symlinks or a repo for your rc files.

Comment: You may have to do this with a batch file rather than a cygwin shell script.  Also, beware of HOME environmental variable conflicts between Windows based gVim and what cgywin will set $HOME as.

Comment: @Heptite I tried to create a bat file for it too. No luck. I get the cannot spawn error mentioned in my question. And you're right about the conflicts. I have not had conflicts with gvim but with git. git config --global under cygwin saves to cygwin home, same under msysgit saves to windows home.

Answer (score 6):

git config seems to remove one level of quotes, so add another. This works for me (with another editor):

> git config core.editor "\"c:/Program Files (x86)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe\""

(Note the escaped quotes surrounding the path, this causes the editor started whenever you do e.g. git commit to be "c:/Program Files (x86)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe", so with quotes that tell the bash shell to not try to interpret the () as whatever it thinks this means.)

Answer (score 0):

When working with spaces in pathnames, it's generally a good idea to encapsulate them in quotes. This will solve your problem:

```
git config core.editor "/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe"
```

Comment: Unfortunately not.
/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe: No such file or directory
error: cannot run /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor '/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe'.

The path is correct though, /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried it with cygwin but I used the cygwin-git package. Could you tell me how you connected cygwin and msysgit?

Comment: I installed msysgit and used git bash for a long time. I don't remember exactly why I started using cygwin, but what I did (do) is I add the path to Git (/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin) to my cygwin $PATH.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/dash -e
if [ "${1#/}" != "$1" ]
then k=$(cygpath -w "$1")
elif [ "$#" != 0 ]
then k=$1
fi
exec gvim ${k+"$k"}
```

1. If no path, pass no path
2. If path is empty, pass empty path
3. If path is relative, pass as is
4. If path is absolute, convert to Windows format

Then I set these variables:

```sh
export EDITOR=gvim.sh
export GIT_EDITOR='dash /usr/local/bin/gvim.sh'
```

1. EDITOR allows script to work with Git
2. GIT_EDITOR allows script to work with [Hub commands](//hub.github.com)

[Source](//github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/tree/6a614d4/notepad2)